# sql server combine values in two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL in general and even newer to MS SQL. I apologize if the title isn't clear on what I want.

I have two tables an old one that I want to derive data from into a new table. The tables have the exact same columns but different number of rows. The new table has multiple copies of each value in the old table, which only has 2 occurences. see below comparison of two columns: letter and amount.

New table:

```
A  0 
A  0
A  0
B  0
B  0
```

old table:

```
A  12
A  0
B  10
B  0
C  23
```

What I want to achieve is adding the values of the amount column from the old table into just the first occurence of the leter in the new table like so:

```
A  12 
A  0
A  0
B  10
B  0
```

Inner join causes all the values to be filled ( so all the A's are set to 12).

Comment: In SQL data does not have an order unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause and that requires data to do the ordering by.  In your case you have three `A` records with `0` and no other differentiating factors.  How do you explicitly know which record should join to which other record?  Are you able to modify your data to add an `id` column using `IDENTITY`?  Also, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2008. I do have an id and it is the same number of occurences in the new table.

Comment: What are the keys on these tables? From teh looks of it you are turning something that shoudl be reasonably simple into a nightmare. First occuurence of A all depends on what order you select them...

Comment: Well tell us teh full structures of the tables then. Without knowing them we can't help.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson hence my asking on an expert forum, for friendly advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @test1 TABLE(col1 varchar(2),idn int)
insert into @test1
VALUES('A',0),
('A',0),
('A',0),
('B',0),
('B',0)

DECLARE @test2 TABLE(col1 varchar(2),idn int)
insert into @test2
VALUES('A',12),
('A',0),
('B',10),
('B',0),
('C',23)


;WITH CTE as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as rn from @test1)

update c SET c.idn=b.idn
from CTE c inner join (select col1,SUM(idn) as idn from @test2
group by col1) b
on c.col1 = b.col1 
where c.rn=1

select * from @test1
```

Comment: The outcome is exactly what I want, can you explain  " ;WITH CTE as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as rn from @test1)"  so I can try it on the actual tables

Comment: Here I am partitioning by col1 so that it will assign the sequence numbers in each partition.Then I will update wherever its 1 with the values from other table.If its useful you can accept the answer.

Comment: Eventually this is the one that was easiest to translate into my library worked perfect Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**[click here to see Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91bc3/1)**

```
declare @t table
(
    val varchar(2),
    digit int
)

insert into @t(val, digit)values('A', 0)
insert into @t(val, digit)values('A', 0)
insert into @t(val, digit)values('A', 0)
insert into @t(val, digit)values('B', 0)
insert into @t(val, digit)values('B', 0)

declare @t1 table
(
    val varchar(2),
    digit int
)

insert into @t1(val, digit)values('A', 12)
insert into @t1(val, digit)values('A', 0)
insert into @t1(val, digit)values('B', 10)
insert into @t1(val, digit)values('B', 0)
insert into @t1(val, digit)values('C', 23)


Select k.val, isNull(sum(k.digit + k1.digit), 0) as Digit from 
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by val order by val) as rowid, * from @t
)K
Left Join
(
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by val order by val) as rowid, * from @t1
)K1
on k.val = k1.val AND K.rowid = K1.rowid
group by k.val, K.rowid
```